# rails - polymorphic association - one-to-one - Form is submiting nested fields with wrong name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have User, which can be one of three types: Admin, Student, Teacher. Everyone has other attributes. I am trying polymorphic association one-to-one like this:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :identity, :polymorphic => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :identity, :allow_destroy => true

    attr_accessible :email, :login, :remember_token, 
                    :password_confirmation, :password, :role
end
```

**Student**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :field

    has_one :user, :as => :identity
end
```

**Controller**

```
def new
     @user = User.new
end
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user]) # It fails here.
    @user.identita.build
    ...
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :login %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :login %>

    <%= f.fields_for [:identity, Student.new] do |i| %>  
    <%= i.label :field %><br />
    <%= i.textfield_select :field  %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit this view (more complex, but this is the core), it sends hash like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "user"=>{"login"=>"...",
 "student"=> {"field"=>"..."}
}
```

So it fails on marked line in controller with:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: student
```

What am I doing wrong? Something like :as=>"student" or twisting the realationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, fix:

```
<%= f.fields_for [:identity, Student.new] do |i| %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :identity, Student.new do |i| %>
```

Secondly, you are trying to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on a `belongs_to` relationship.  This is not supported behavior AFAIK.  Perhaps try moving that to the `Student` model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :field

  has_one :user, :as => :identity
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and make the view like this:

```
<%= form_for(Student.new) do |i| %>
  <%= i.fields_for :user, @user do |f| %>  
    <%= f.label :login %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :login %>
  <% end %>
  <%= i.label :field %><br />
  <%= i.textfield_select :field  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I fixed the first one, but the second one didn't helped... I am getting this error now (both with the second one advice applied and not):
`ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: identity_attributes`

Comment: Well, It was really late night hour... Now I tried it once more, and I succeeded... Thank you very much :)

The result is three controllers and every one has link to general user information.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation of attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class)

> attr_accessible will only set attributes in this list, **to assign to**
>    **the rest of attributes** you can use direct writer methods.

So once you've used `attr_accessible`, another attributes automatically will become a protected ones.

Comment: but there should not be student, but identity, or not?